# C# Entity [AllowHtml] does not work with other ModelState validation errors

Tags: c#, html, validation, entity

```
public class Test
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [NumberUnique]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Html)]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Cases:
Unique Number and HTML Description: **works**
Unique Number and Non-HTML Description: **works**
Non-Unique Number and Non-HTML Description: **works** (throws proper validation errors)
Non-Unique Number and HTML Description : **Breaks** ( potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

I know the validation is correct by looking at the ModelState object for each combination in the controller.
Any ideas why I get an dangerous request error when other validation errors are present?

Comment: Can you show us some sample text that works and that shows the dangerous value?

Comment: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>test</p></body></html>". Strange thing is this HTML works fine when the Number is unique. If it is not unique, it complains about the HTML when it should complain about the Number not being unique.

Comment: What number? I can't see any number in the text?

Comment: The property on class Test named Number which has the Unique requirement.